# How to make fields available to users in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, entities, users

I want users to participate in creating some content. I allowed them (people/permissions)  to create own content on particular content type. The question is: how to provide them access to fields of content type, that are available to me as administrator? In other words, I can put content in fields through my admin panel, but how to make users possible to meet that fields, how to make fields  public?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't get the meaning of - 'but how to make users possible to meet that fields'. Considering, the content type is 'Hotel' & you want say, all the authenticated users be able to create content of type 'Hotel' and so associate data with the various fields, then you need to add permission 'Hotel: Create new content' by visiting 'admin/people/permissions'. If you need some role based permissioning, that you can control accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, all the fields added to an entity are visible to every user who has permission to create or edit entities of that type. (In the case of nodes, the users needs the permission to create or edit nodes of that content type.) [field_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_access/7) is the function that determines which users have access to a field, but Drupal doesn't implement [hook_field_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7).
If the field is not visible to the other users, check you don't have a module that implements `hook_field_access()`, such as the [Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module. If you have one of those modules, check their settings.

Alternatively, there is a module that makes the field not visible to the users. Also in this case, check its settings or temporary disable it to see if the field is visible to any other user.

Comment: Thanks, bit still I don't see how to display empty field box to user. It should be like webform field. One page with empty fields, that users populate with information. How to make page that displays empty fields?

Comment: For example, as administrator I can create Content type, and if I want to add some content, I have to go to content/add content, then choose content type, and empty fields appears. My question is: how to make page page that displays empty fields for users to type into?

Answer (score 1):

Give "Create content" permission to the user type who can create content at your instance.

There is the [Field Permission module](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) which lets you specify permissions for each field in a entity. You can set permission for each field by help of this module.